# Import my MS SQL Server DB into my Android Application that runs SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, sqlite, ssms

I have created a DB in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) complete with primary and foreign keys as well as the inserts.

i am currently creating the Android application for that Database. I understand that Android runs on SQL lite and that my stored procedures are useless, but do i have to re-build the database??

is there a way i can convert that DB into a Lite version and then import or add it to my android project?, complete with the inserts and foreign and primary keys. Furthermore is it true that Lite now supports Foreign keys? i get conflicting reports on the net about it
and would love a once and for all answer.

my DB relies on many foreign keys in order to keep everything lightweight

I am working with Eclipse (with the ADK Bundle) and am extremely new to android

Comment: "my DB relies on many foreign keys in order to keep everything lightweight " - statement makes NO sense. Foreign keys are there to model the domain.

Comment: What the OP means, the schema is highly normalized to keep data duplication to a minimum. In practice - lotsa lookup tables.

Comment: 2CodeKuga88: It all depends on how are you going to work with the data in the Android app. Are you shipping the prefilled database (the .db file) with the app? If so find a GUI client for SQLite (I like [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/)) and use it to run the SQL script against the database.

Answer (score 1):

Script  the MS SQL database and then run those scripts on the SQL Lite database. That is the easiest and quickest way.

Update:

So you now have scripts that you need to run on the SQLite database. Understand that some of the scripts might not work. I would suggest that you first translate the script from TSQL(MS SQL Server) to SQLite syntax. Dont worry this step will be relatively easy and so will the rest. See [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Connecting_to_SQLite) link on how to connect from Eclipse to SQLite database. This will allow you to create a SQLite database on your local machine to help the ease of getting the scripts sorted out.

Once you have the script ready to run on Android see [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/) link on how to deploy your database to your android application.

Important to keep in mind is that SQLite on android is not a fully fledged SQL server but rather a embedded database.

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: well that doesnt make sense, as you haven't explained to me how that works?

Comment: Go google it. You will need to know how to script a database.

Comment: Okay so I've scripted the DB, i still dont get how i turn it into an sqlite Db and then import it into my android app?

Comment: Now you are asking correct questions.